# Extracting value inside HTML tag

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am writing a JAVA program trying to extract values from the source code:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 287px; height: 205px;border:1px solid#cccccc;"></div> 
</div> <input type="hidden" id="googleMap" value="22.360883564467176,114.13237318305971"> <input type="hidden" id="cpId" value="512">
```

How can I extract the values 22.360883564467176,114.13237318305971 from the code with JAVA?

```
String connect = url.toString();
doc = Jsoup.connect(connect).get();
```

I have only created a document to get the codes from the web.

Comment: did you follow a tutorial ?? you have to do something with selectors ,attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for get attribute which is named `value` in tag id `googleMap`

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element element = document.getElementById("googleMap");

String value = element.attr("value");
```